# How to show only 2 items in RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, listadapter

There is a list of operations that I display in the recyclerview through the ListAdapter. The size of the RecyclerView is 2 elements.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7U1Cg.png)

ListAdapter:

```
class OperationAdapter(private val onItemClicked: (Operation) -> Unit) :
ListAdapter<Operation, OperationAdapter.OperationViewHolder>(DiffCallback) {



override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): OperationViewHolder {
    val viewHolder = OperationViewHolder(
        OperationItemBinding.inflate(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
            parent,
            false
        )
    )

    return viewHolder
}

@SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor", "SetTextI18n")
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: OperationViewHolder, position: Int) {

    holder.bind(getItem(position))
}


class OperationViewHolder(private var binding: OperationItemBinding): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
    /*val imageOperation:ImageView = view.findViewById(R.id.imageViewItem)
    val nameOperation:TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.name_operation)
    val balanceOperation:TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.textSum)*/
    fun bind(operation: Operation){
        if(operation.receive == ACCOUNT.number){
            binding.imageViewItem.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_type_recieve)

            binding.nameOperation.text = operation.send
            binding.nameOperation.setTextColor(Color.rgb(35, 135, 0))

            val sum = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale("en", "US")).format(operation.sum)
            binding.textSum.text = sum
            binding.textSum.setTextColor(Color.rgb(35, 135, 0))
        }else{
            binding.imageViewItem.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_type_sent)

            binding.nameOperation.text = operation.receive
            binding.nameOperation.setTextColor(Color.rgb(231, 223,255))

            val sum = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale("en", "US")).format(operation.sum)
            binding.textSum.text = "-$sum"
            binding.textSum.setTextColor(Color.rgb(231, 223,255))
        }
    }
}

companion object{
    private val DiffCallback = object: DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Operation>(){
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Operation, newItem: Operation): Boolean {
            return oldItem.id == newItem.id
        }

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Operation, newItem: Operation): Boolean {
            return oldItem == newItem
        }

    }
}
```

}

I retrieve list from Room by courotine:

```
  GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO){
        sharedViewModel.getOperationsAll(ACCOUNT.number).collect(){ it ->
            operationAdapter.submitList(it.sortedByDescending { it.time })
        }
    }
```

I cannot output recycler view with only two items, where user can scroll it.

Answer (score 1):

You must not use GlobalScope for this, because it will leak your Activity and/or Fragment for the entire lifetime of your app. Every time the screen changes, it'll leak another copy of it until your app runs out of memory.

Dispatchers.IO is unnecessary. You are not calling any blocking functions in this coroutine.

To limit to two items, you can use `take(2)` on the list before you pass it to the adapter:

```
lifecycleScope.launch {
    sharedViewModel.getOperationsAll(ACCOUNT.number).collect { opList ->
        operationAdapter.submitList(opList.sortedByDescending { it.time }.take(2))
    }
}
```

If this is a Fragment, you should use `viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope` instead.

Comment: how to scroll it?

Comment: What do you mean? Why would you need to scroll only two items?